# Problems with Forms2Go script

Tags: perl, email, webforms

I am currently trying to make a form for a website in work. I have created the script in Perl using Forms2Go and have entered the send mail and bin paths given to me. At the first the script wouldn't execute but the hosts made changes to the sever and now it does.

Problem now is the script executes and takes the user to the thank you page but doesn't send the form to the e-mail address which has been tested by the hosting company.

I have a feeling that the send-mail path isn't correct and that is why it is executing but not sending the email, anything else it might be?

Thanks for reading.

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Forms To Go](http://www.bebosoft.com/products/formstogo/overview/) is payware and they do not provide their source code publicly which makes trouble-shooting by the general Internet populace rather difficult. Try [their support forum](http://support.bebosoft.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=2) instead. If you're looking for a form mailer that does not suck, install [nms TFMail](http://nms-cgi.sourceforge.net/scripts.shtml).

Comment: Woops I forgot to change the title from something I already figured out lol. Thanks for the tip I will check it out.